# Remove underline on before with display flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a footer menu with a list of links with a chevron in the :before. I want the chevron to clear the space beneath (like in my examples), with the links neatly listed to the right. The problem is I can't get this to work in combination with a removed underline on the chevron because of the display: flex. Either the chevron doesn't clear but without the underline, or the chevron clears with an underline. Does anyone know how to achieve both with CSS?

I included 2 examples: the first has a correct clearing and the second one is supposed to remove the underline in the chevron, tho this only works in chrome.

CSS:

```
.list-unstyled {
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.footerblock1 li a {
    color: #535353;
    display: flex;
}

.footerblock1 li a:before {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-right: 8px;
    content:"\f105";
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

.footerblock2 li a {
    color: #535353;
    display: flex;
}

.footerblock2 li a:before {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-right: 8px;
    content:"\f105";
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-table;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 footerblock1">
    <div class="well well-lg">
        <h2>Footerhead 1</h2>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li><a href="#">Footerlink</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Footerlink Footerlink Footerlink Footerlink Footerlink Footerlink Footerlink</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FooterlinkFooterlink Footerlink Footerlink Footerlink Footerlink</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--Well-->
</div> <!--col-sm-6-->

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 footerblock2">
    <div class="well well-lg">
        <h2>Footerhead 1</h2>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li><a href="#">Footerlink</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Footerlink Footerlink Footerlink Footerlink Footerlink Footerlink Footerlink</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FooterlinkFooterlink Footerlink Footerlink Footerlink Footerlink</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--Well-->
</div> <!--col-sm-6-->
```

JSFIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/0h4zft7u/2/

Comment: .footerblock1 li a{text-decoration: none;} this works. why you have given in a:before?

Comment: @punithasubramaniv - I assume they want the link underlined, just not the `:before` pseudo element.

Comment: That line removes the underline on the text as well, which I want to keep. I just want to remove the underline on the chevron.

Comment: Acutualy there is no underline in :before. try content : 'test'; updated my post. kindly try it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers! I managed to get it to work with the following CSS:

```
    .list-unstyled {
        padding-left: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }

    .footerblock1 li a {
        color: #535353;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }

    .footerblock1 li a:before {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        font-family: 'FontAwesome';
        font-weight: normal;
        margin-right: 8px;
        content:"\f105";
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

FIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/0h4zft7u/6/

Comment: Please accept this as the correct answer so that it is more clear to readers that you have fixed it :)

Comment: smart :) saved me a headache

Answer (score 3):

there is a good replacement `flex` `inline-block`

```
.footerblock2 li a {
    color: #535353;
    display: flex;/*change at inline-block;*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Acutualy there is no underline in :before.

content not showing properly to me,

try content as

```
content : 'test';  text-decoration: none; /*This will not come with underline*/
```

You will see the difference

```
content : 'test';  text-decoration: underline; /*This will come with underline*/
```

If you are changing

```
display: flex;
```

to

```
display: inline-block;
```

this will work

Comment: I updated the JSFIDDLE to display X's instead of chevrons: http://jsfiddle.net/0h4zft7u/3/

Comment: why you are using flex? I dont know about flex.

Comment: changing display: flex; to display: inline-block;

Answer (score 0):

- Apply the `:before` pseudo element to the `<li>`
- Give the `li:before` the `display: inline-block` or `display: inline` property to bring it in line with the `<a>`

[Have an example!](http://jsfiddle.net/uxztm3xe/1/)

```
.footerblock2 li:before {
    font-family:'FontAwesome';
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-right: 8px;
    content:"X";
    display: inline-block;
}
```